# Make Linux taskbar show preview like Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, taskbar

In Windows 7 when you hover over an open application in the taskbar, it shows a small image of that application. Is there a way this can be done in Linux?

Comment: Which desktop environment are we talking about?

Gnome? KDE? WindowManager? xfce? ...?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. How do I find out what desktop environment it's using? I think it's Gnome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install compizconfig-settings-manager from your package manager and activate window previews under misc.

This of course will only work if you have compiz running.

Comment: If I type compiz in the terminal then it shows some error messages, says its falling back on some other window program, and messes up the windows.

Comment: You want to start compiz from the Appearance menu (3d effects). If switching to compiz fails it will fall back to your current window manager without the cluttering. If it fails to enable compiz your video driver is missing required features. Try a different one (e.g. unfree driver) if it still fails there is not much you can do apart from waiting.

Comment: Was able to install compiz from Ubuntu Tweak and got the preview working.